# Can I view the LogCat output for a tablet if there is no USB driver for it?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just purchased a MATPC M7 tablet (aka the TabTech M7) hoping to use it for developing applications. One key issue is that I need to see the tablet's LogCat output. Unfortunately I have since heard that there is no Windows USB driver for this tablet and when I use "adb logcat" I see nothing when my app runs. Is there any way round this?

Comment: not really. if you have an option to send all logging to an external logging system via wifi or else. otherwise it's not possible. you have to have a driver in order to use adb. read this if need be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283049/adb-logcat-on-a-real-phone-using-tcp-ip

Comment: Or you install aLogCat to see your logcat output. Here it is: https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out Ubuntu because then you don't need drivers. If you don't want to install it permanently then you can also try it on a USB stick or CDR.